# pickle data was truncated

Tags: python, data-science, pickle, data-science-experience

i created a corpus file then stored in a pickle file.
my messages file is a collection of different news articles dataframe.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import re
ps = PorterStemmer()
corpus = []
for i in range(0, len(messages)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', messages['text'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()

    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    #print(i)
    corpus.append(review)

import pickle
with open('corpus.pkl', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(corpus, f)
```

same code I ran on my laptop (jupyter notebook) and on google colab.

corpus.pkl => Google colab, downloaded with the following code:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('corpus.pkl')
```

corpus1.pkl => saved from jupyter notebook code.

now When I run this code:

```py
import pickle
with open('corpus.pkl', 'rb') as f:   # google colab
    corpus = pickle.load(f)
```

I get the following error:

```
UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

But this works fine:

```py
import pickle
with open('corpus1.pkl', 'rb') as f:  # jupyter notebook saved
    corpus = pickle.load(f)
```

The only difference between both is that `corpus1.pkl` is run and saved through Jupyter notebook (on local) and `corpus.pkl` is saved on google collab and downloaded.

Could anybody tell me why is this happening?

for reference..

```
corpus.pkl  => 36 MB
corpus1.pkl => 50.5 MB
```

Comment: You should rather show how you generate the files, since it looks like they are being read with the very same code.

Comment: There are multiple points of failure here: [colab] -> [download from colab] -> [something in the network before your machine].  I guess you tried to download it again, and check the file size in colab before downloading.

Comment: I am using the same code to create both files, just one in my  laptop (jupyter notebook) and other in google callab.

Comment: The suggestion by @Iñigo worked. I also had uploaded the pickle file in Google Collab but was experiencing the same error as yours. I just deleted the uploaded file and re-uploaded it and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use pickle file created by my local machine only, that works properly

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs due to partial download of glove vectors. I have uploaded the data through colab upload to session storage and after that simply write this command:

```py
with open('/content/glove_vectors', 'rb') as f: 
    model = pickle.load(f)
    glove_words =  set(model.keys())
```